# Getting Stripe call to resolve in GraphQL schema

Tags: javascript, graphql, stripe-payments, graphql-js

I am trying to create an API endpoint using GraphQL and stripe, however I can't get the data to resolve correctly with Stripe's asynchronous call, instead it returns undefined.

Here is the call:

```
app.use('/', graphqlHTTP(req => {
const charges = limit => stripe.charges.list({ limit: limit }, (err, charges) => {
    charges = _.orderBy(charges, "created", "desc")
    return charges
})
return {
    schema,
    context: {
        charges
    },
    graphiql: true
}
}))
```

Here is the schema:

```
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'StripeCharges',
    description: 'These are Stripe charges made to store',
    fields: () => ({
        stripeCharge: {
            type: GraphQLList(StripeChargeType),
            args: {
                limit: { type: GraphQLInt }
            },
            resolve: (root, args, context, info) => {
                console.log(context.charges(args.limit))
                return context.charges(args.limit)
            }
        }
    })
 })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a value inside a callback conventionally doesn't do anything. When you include a callback, `charges.list` will immediately return `undefined` and will call the callback when the operation completes.

You **could** continue to use a callback and wrap it in a Promise, but there's no need to do that since stripe's library supports Promises. Just don't pass in a callback, and instead of `undefined`, `charges.list` will return a Promise that will eventually resolve to the list of charges.

```
function getCharges (limit) {
  return stripe.charges.list({ limit: limit }) // returns a promise
    .then(charges => {
      return _.orderBy(charges, "created", "desc")
    })
}

// with async/await, async functions always return a Promise
async function getCharges (limit) {
  const charges = await stripe.charges.list({ limit: limit })
  return _.orderBy(charges, "created", "desc")
}
```

Your resolver can return either a value or a Promise that will resolve to that value, so we can just return the value returned by `getCharges`:

```
resolve: (root, args, context, info) => getCharges(args.limit)
```

Or if you wanted to manipulate the charges inside the resolver

```
resolve: async (root, args, context, info) => {
  let charges = await getCharges(args.limit)
  // do whatever
  return charges
}
```

Also, for what it's worth, according to the docs the charges are already returned sorted by creation date:

> The charges are returned in sorted order, with the most recent charges appearing first.